# Magnolia - FileNotFoundException to find the Template on windows

Tags: magnolia

I am following the initial Magnolia tutorial, [Tutorial](https://academy.magnolia-cms.com/display/MA/2+Step+by+step+instructions)

While I am trying step 4 , I am getting Error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template"\\myTemplate\\pages\\myPage.ftl" not found.

Since I am on windows 7 I have specified teplateScript path as `\myTemplate\pages\myPage.ftl` (with forward slash)

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception suggest you used backward slash instead of forward. Try to write it with forward slash like `/myTemplate/pages/myPage.ftl`. Make sure file really exists in your module under this path starting from `/src/main/resources`. It is case sensitive so make sure cases match the real path too.  If that doesn't help try to specify better what step you are failing there's step 4 in pretty much each part. Full stacktrace for exception would also help.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks, I think I have mixed up forward and back slashes !