# Magnolia cms - FileNotFoundException error when finding template on windows

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, magnolia

I am following a Hello World Magnolia tutorial found on their documentation site.

Everything works out fine until step 4 when I try to load the template. This is the screen I get when I try to preview the template: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDjoB.png

And this is how my content node is set up: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh8Qh.png

I've tried using both forward and backward slashes. This was put forth as an answer to the question on the same subject. It was asked few months back but was seemingly unresolved.

At least, changing from backward to forward slashes didn't fix the problem for me.

I've also tried to include in templateScript `/myTemplateModule/src/main/resources/` in every combination (i.e. `/resources/myTemplateModule/..` and `main/resources/..` and so on)`

So, I am thinking this is some configuration problem where Magnolia is searching in the wrong place (other than `/myTemplateModule/src/main/resources`) but I don't know enough about Magnolia to know where that configuration would be.

Can someone help me, please?

I am using Magnolia v5.4 on a Windows 7, Intellij IDEA v14.4 with Tomcat 8.0.24 and Maven 3.3.3.

*Links are in the comments.*

Comment: Magnolia - FileNotFoundException to find the Template on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616520/magnolia-filenotfoundexception-to-find-the-template-on-windows/31909591

Comment: Hello World tutorial: https://academy.magnolia-cms.com/display/MA/Hello+World+-+step+by+step

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post images or more than 2 links. If someone could edit. it would be great :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the first / in the path `myTemplateModule/pages/hello.ftl` and put the file in the directory resources/pages

Comment: But I found a solution to my problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!

I added a folder called `templates` between my `myTemplateModule` and `pages` folders, so the full path ended up to be: `/myTemplateModule/templates/pages/hello.ftl`

I'm not sure though why this works. It worked even though I had not changed the "templateScript" node from old path to the new.

If anybody can comment or put up an answer about how this works, that would be awesome! :D